# How to interpret results of Linear Regression after log-transforming the target variable?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I built Liear Regression model in Python and I had target variable for example Sales: 10, 9, 8.
I decided to log my target variable: `df["Sales"] = np.log(df["Sales"])`so I have after that values np 3, 2, 1.

My question is how can I interpretate results of this model being aware that my target was log ? Because currently I have interpretation for example: If there is night sales decrease average by 1.333 nevertheless it is probably bad interpretation because without log of target I will have result in definitely higher quantification like If there is night sales decrease average by for example 2 589.

So how can I interpretate results of Linear Regression after log of target ? Because after log target has really low values ?

Comment: I don't see a programming issue here, so SO is probably not the best place to ask this. You might want to have a  look at an introductory econometrics book to see in what cases  log transformation makes sense and how to interpret it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transformation is called a "log-level" regression. That is, your target variable was log-transformed and your independent variables are left in their normal scales.

The model should be interpreted as follows:

> On average, a marginal change in `X_i` will cause a change of `100 * B_i` percent.

Do note that if you transformed any of your independent variables, the interpretation will change too. For example, if you changed `X_i` to `np.log(df['X_i`])`, then you would interpret` B_i` as a log-log transformation.

You can find a handy cheat sheet to help you remember how to interpret models [here](http://www.cazaar.com/ta/econ113/interpreting-beta).

Comment: link is dead;...